# write.csv() a list of unequally sized data.frames

Tags: r

I would like to pump out a list of data.frame() objects to a csv file so I can work on it for presentation. I'm finding that it's replying with an error:

```
In write.csv(tmp[i], file = "Output.csv", append = T) :
  attempt to set 'append' ignored
```

I've saved the outputs to a list (all of which can be coerced to a df), here's an example:

```
outputs <- list() 
outputs$fivenum <- fivenum(rnorm(100))
outputs$summary <- as.data.frame(as.vector(summary(rnorm(100))))

tmp <- lapply(outputs, as.data.frame)

write.csv(tmp, file="Output.csv",append=T)
```

Does every append action have to have the same number of columns?

Comment: Yes, if you use `write.csv`.  I think you can get round this by using `write.table(..., sep=",", append=TRUE`) - but I haven't tested this recently.

Comment: @Andrie: you can't append with `write.csv` ever. Just like you can't change `col.names`, `sep`, `dec`, or `qmethod`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich That's what I thought I said, but clearly the meaning was lost in translation.

Comment: @Andrie: I thought you were answering "does every append action have to have the same number of columns?".  You can still append even if the objects don't have to have the same number of columns, but that creates a funky file.

Comment: Why not rbind.fill them together first?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's a warning, not an error.  You can't change `append=FALSE` with `write.csv`.  `?write.csv` says:

> Attempts to change ‘append’, ‘col.names’, ‘sep’, ‘dec’ or ‘qmethod’
>   are ignored, with a warning.

Use `write.table` with `sep=","` instead.

Comment: +1 Yep, that's what I had in mind in my comment to the main question.

Comment: is there a work around? I have a few clients who like to get things in excel. So I need to pump out an excel file of outputs (with elements in the cells rather than in the first cell and having to convert text to columns)

Comment: @Brandon: how about `sapply(tmp, write.table, file="Output.csv", append=TRUE, sep=",")`?

Comment: Ah, there we go. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can now export multiple dataframes in a single CSV using [sheetr](https://github.com/d-notebook/sheetr)

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

# Install package from github
install_github('d-notebook/sheetr')
library(sheetr)

# Create a list of dataframes
iris_dataframe = list()
iris_dataframe[["Setosa subset"]] = head(iris[iris$Species == "setosa",])
iris_dataframe[["Versicolor subset"]] = head(iris[iris$Species == "versicolor",])

# Write the list of dataframes to CSV file
write_dataframes_to_csv(iris_dataframe, "exmaple_csv.csv")
```

Which will export:

[image: screenshot]

.
.

Or, if you prefer to do that manually, you can use `sink` files:

```
# Sample dataframes:
df1 = iris[1:5, ]
df2 = iris[20:30, ]

# Start a sink file with a CSV extension
sink('multiple_df_export.csv')

 # Write the first dataframe, with a title and final line separator 
cat('This is the first dataframe')
write.csv(df1)
cat('____________________________')

cat('\n')
cat('\n')

# Write the 2nd dataframe to the same sink
cat('This is the second dataframe')
write.csv(df2)
cat('____________________________')

# Close the sink
sink()
```

Comment: `sheetr`! Thats a great feature to be able to do it. Thanks!