# Write different data frame in one .csv file with R

Tags: r, file, csv, dataframe, append

I have 3 data frame, and I want them to be written in one single .csv file, one above the others, not in a same table. So, 3 different tables in one csv file. They all have same size.

The problem with `write.csv`: it does not contain "*append*" feature

The problem with `write.table`:  csv files from `write.table` are not read prettily by Excel 2010 like those from `write.csv`

[image: Here is with <code>write.csv</code>]

[image: Here is with <code>write.table</code>]

Post I already read and in which I could not find solution to my problem :

- [write.csv() a list of unequally sized data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351049/write-csv-a-list-of-unequally-sized-data-frames)
- [Creating a file with more than one data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753340/creating-a-file-with-more-than-one-data-frame)

Solution ?

Comment: Excel can import text files (tab separated/fixed width). See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010342598.aspx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`write.csv` just calls `write.table` under the hood, with appropriate arguments. So you can achieve what you want with 3 calls to `write.table`.

```
write.table(df1, "filename.csv", col.names=TRUE, sep=",")
write.table(df2, "filename.csv", col.names=FALSE, sep=",", append=TRUE)
write.table(df3, "filename.csv", col.names=FALSE, sep=",", append=TRUE)
```

Actually, you could avoid the whole issue by combining your data frames into a single df with rbind, then calling write.csv once.

```
write.csv(rbind(df1, d32, df3), "filename.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but `write.table` is not the solution... I updated my question.. please take a look at pictures I uploaded

Comment: Just try it and see what happens.

Comment: And how do you read from a file like this?

Answer (score 14):

We use `sink` files:

```
# Sample dataframes:
df1 = iris[1:5, ]
df2 = iris[20:30, ]

# Start a sink file with a CSV extension
sink('multiple_df_export.csv')

 # Write the first dataframe, with a title and final line separator 
cat('This is the first dataframe')
write.csv(df1)
cat('____________________________')

cat('\n')
cat('\n')

# Write the 2nd dataframe to the same sink
cat('This is the second dataframe')
write.csv(df2)
cat('____________________________')

# Close the sink
sink()
```